# How can I get a string from FormData in asp.net, sent from Angular?

Tags: asp.net, angular

So I am trying to make a post (for example like those on Facebook) which contain a title, description and an image. I do this using Angular and ASP.NET CORE. My DB structure is that I save my image on the wwwroot server folder and want to create a Table 'posts' that contains a link to this folder for getting the image.

Creating a post and sending an image both work, but now I want to send my Object 'Post' and my image (FormData) in one HttpPost. However it doesn't seem to work.

**Frontend Angular**

```
onSubmit(Image) {
    let post = new Post(this.post.value.titel, this.post.value.omschrijving, new Date(), this._userService.user$.getValue())
    this._postService.voegPostToe(post, this.selectedFile).subscribe();
    this.post.reset();
  } 

voegPostToe(post: Post, fileToUpload: File) {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('Image', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
    formData.append('ObjectData', JSON.stringify(post));
    return this.http.post(`${environment.apiUrl}/posts`, formData);
  }
```

**Backend ASP.NET**

```
 [HttpPost]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Post>> PostPost()
        {
            Post resource = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Post>(HttpContext.Request.Form["ObjectData"]);
            var file = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files["Image"];
            string fileName = new String(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName).Take(10).ToArray()).Replace(" ", "-");
            fileName = fileName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

            string filePath = _env.WebRootPath + "\\Images\\" + fileName;
            using (var fileSrteam = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await file.CopyToAsync(fileSrteam);
            }

            resource.Fotolink = filePath;

            _postRepository.Add(resource);
            _postRepository.SaveChanges();

            return NoContent();
        }
```

My problem is that I don't know how to convert the stringified Object to the Object's class in ASP.NET, I always seem to get a BadRequest error.

Comment: return this.http.post(`${environment.apiUrl}/posts`, JSON.stringify(formData));

Comment: This gives an internal server error

Comment: In the browser inspector do you see correct header sent ?

Comment: headers: HttpHeaders
lazyInit: ƒ ()
lazyUpdate: null
normalizedNames: Map(0) {}
__proto__: Object
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/api/posts: 500 Internal Server Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 500
statusText: "Internal Server Error"
url: "http://localhost:4200/api/posts"

Comment: post variable has the data or formData which is to be sent ?  you are doing JSON.stringify(post)  but actually sending formData

Comment: I need to both send formData (my image) and an object "post"